# How to get CGPoint inside a circular UIView in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have set `UIView` corner radius with both using `UIBezierPath` and `setCornerRadius`. check below code:

```
func roundCorners(cornerRadius: Double) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.puttingView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.puttingView.bounds
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.puttingView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
```

Now I am setting `UITapGestureRecognizer` on `UIView` when I try to click on outside `UIView` corner radius and the `UIView` is clickable.
So I don't want to get `CGPoint` outside corner radius.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@objc func tapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let loc:CGPoint = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
        if let layer = puttingView.layer.mask, layer.bounds.contains(loc){
            print("inside")
        }
    }
```

Comment: @iOS, Please log the value of loc and bounds of layer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

you may need to implement this

```
func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all conform your `controller` to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and implement `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)` method.

Return `true`, if the `touch` lies inside the `mask`, and `false` otherwise.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let frame = self.puttingView.layer.mask?.bounds
    let location = touch.location(in: self.puttingView)
    if frame?.contains(location) ?? false {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Don't forget to set the `delegate` of the `gestureRecognizer` you're adding to the `puttingView`, i.e.

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped(_:)))
gesture.delegate = self //here......
self.puttingView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```